# What real world projects based on Windows Embedded do you know?

Tags: windows-embedded

What real world project based on Windows Embedded do you know? Please provide some details such as description, project domain, key feature and why Windows Embedded is used?

Answer (score 1):

You can find real world project in the case study page of the [Windows Embedded Web site](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/about/casestudies.mspx). All the products described there are actual products running Windows Embedded and industrialized.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can think of is a nice simple library implementation where silent machines are in use and as such low power is needed. Their machines only connect to the internet and are fan-less. I could imagine the same argument used in radio station studios instead of KVM to a server room.

Sorry these are a little boring but that's all I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Can't disclose the details. But most of the navigation displays on some very large ships are running Delphi on XP-embedded.
Anywhere that you aren't trying to save the last few c, you can fit a PC104 board with a low power x86 CPU and you want a reasonably same development environment it's a good choice.